# Which is better check the integer is 0 or check the variable is null?

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I tried to search the internet but I didn't see it's been asked. So our lecturer told us, we must write our own linked-list from scratch. Inside the linkedlist have head and tail pointing at another when you add item. Suppose if inside I already add a working integer counter. My question is I have 2 option to check if the linkedlist is empty:

1. check the head is null
2. check the counter is 0

my question is which is better in term of efficiency? I know the checking is millisecond matter, but I want to know, in theory, which one got better advantage over another? Sorry I'm not taking Operating System, I not know much the theory.

Comment: First option. It does not depend on your counter implementation.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To improve your question I suggest you try being a little more specific. Questions asking "which is better" tend to produce opinionated answers. Are you asking whether one has better performance?

Comment: What is the "working integer counter"? Are you just keeping track of how big the list is? _Why_ are you checking this? My guess is -- "what should I check to see if the list is empty?" but you don't really say that.

Comment: yes, performance wise. And reply Stephan P, for various reason like you store text line by line you can call the counter directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking which has better performance, they'll be exactly the same. In both cases you're doing a field or property access followed by a numeric comparison against a constant value. (`null` is just `0` as a memory address.)